# <select> should have {defaultValue} or {value} instead of setting {selected}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm building an E-Commerce site with reactjs with styled-component.
My page **product.jsx** that has the `<select>` element with different sizes of product `[XS,S,M,L,XL]` that causes error always shows this error upon render in console.dev:

> Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on  instead of setting `selected` on .

I tried this code right below before but it doesn't work as expected. I'm expecting to show the first element as disabled and shouldn't be selected at all:

```
<Filter>
  <FilterTitle>Size</FilterTitle>
    <FilterSize onChange={(e) => setSize(e.target.value)}>
        {product.size?.map((s) => (
              <FilterSizeOption key={s}>{s}</FilterSizeOption>
        ))}
  </FilterSize>
</Filter>
```

---

Please help me fix this code below not the above one.

**product.jsx** code:

```
const FilterSize = styled.select`
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0px;
  font-size: inherit;
`;
const FilterSizeOption = styled.option``;

//...

<Filter>
    <FilterTitle>Size</FilterTitle>
    <FilterSize onChange={(e) => setSize(e.target.value)}>
         <FilterSizeOption selected={true} disabled="disabled">
              Choose a size:
         </FilterSizeOption>
         {product?.product?.size.map((s) => (
              <FilterSizeOption key={s} value={s}>
                   {s}
              </FilterSizeOption>
         ))}
    </FilterSize>
</Filter>
```

Comment: Have you built a filter component? If so, please provide component source. Or are are you importing it? If you so, please provide package/library.

Comment: Would also help to understand what you are trying to do. I assume you want a product size selected by default? Is that correct?

Comment: yeah, that's correct @jmtornetta, it's just a `<select>` with element of different size of products like: **XS,S,M,L,XL**. simple like that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this error you need change `value="default"` instead of `selected={true}`, and on the **FilterSize** component should add `defaultValue="default"`. The **defaultValue** and **value** with the same value, you will bind the default selection. The **default** value you can rename yourself.

##### Before

[image]

##### After

[image]

```js
const FilterSize = styled.select`
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0px;
  font-size: inherit;
`;
const FilterSizeOption = styled.option``;

const sizes = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'];

function App() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <FilterSize defaultValue="default" onChange={e => setSize(e.target.value)}>
        <FilterSizeOption value="default" disabled="disabled">
          Choose a size:
        </FilterSizeOption>
        {sizes.map(s => (
          <FilterSizeOption key={s} value={s}>
            {s}
          </FilterSizeOption>
        ))}
      </FilterSize>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```